# LInq to Entity select new COUNT where

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

I've created the most complex linq query ever, but still do not have exactly what I need. From this query, I need to know how many related students in the EventStudents table that have a `DateDeleted == null`. So, the StudentCount = ev.EventStudents - where DateDeleted == null .Count().
Can anyone help with this please?

```
var inf = (from ev in db.Events
       where (ev.StartDate >= beginDate && ev.StartDate <= endDate)
        && ev.DeletedDate == null
       orderby ev.StartDate descending
       select new
      {
          EventID = ev.EventID,
          EventTitle = ev.Title,
          EventDate = ev.StartDate,
          StudentCount = ev.EventStudents.Count(),
          CreatedUsername = ev.CreatedUsername
      }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new
      {
          EventID = x.EventID,
          EventTitle = x.EventTitle,
          EventDate = x.EventDate,
          StudentCount = x.StudentCount,
          CreatedUsername = x.CreatedUsername,
          CreatedFullname = sortedUserDictionary.Where(u => u.Value == x.CreatedUsername)
          .Select(f => f.Key)
          .FirstOrDefault() ?? x.CreatedUsername
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `ev.EventStudents.Count()` to `ev.EventStudents.Count(es => es.DateDeleted == null)`.